# Filtering a multidimensional array in PowerShell

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm looking for some advice on filtering a multidimensional array and whether there are better ways over my existing approach.

I am filtering a multidimensional array where multiple values could be Null, "", " " etc. (i.e. they don't have what I've determined as valid values). The array looks like this:

```
$Files.Path
$Files.Owner
$Files.Vendor
$Files.Company
$Files.Product
$Files.Description
$Files.ProductVersion
$Files.FileVersion
```

To filter on Vendor, Company, Product, Description, I could do this a couple ways:

Method 1:

```
$Values = @(" ", "", $Null)
$NoMetadata = $Files | Where-Object {
    ($Values -contains $_.Vendor) -and `
    ($Values -contains $_.Company) -and `
    ($Values -contains $_.Product) -and `
    ($Values -contains $_.Description)
}
```

Method 2:

```
$NoMetadata = $Files | Where-Object { $_.Vendor -le 1 -and `
$_.Company -le 1 -and $_.Product -le 1 -and $_.Description -le 1 }
```

I appreciate any advice on improving my approach.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest defining a **helper function** (using the simpler `-le 1` conditional from your Method 2, which returns `$True` for `$null`, `""` and `" "` alike):

```
Function test-NoMetaData {
  param([object] $obj)
  # Loop over all property names and inspect that property's value on the input object.
  foreach ($propName in 'Vendor', 'Company', 'Product', 'Description') {
    if ($obj.$propName -le 1) { return $False }
  }
  return $True
}

# Filter $Files down to those objects that lack the (complete) metadata.
$filesWithoutMetaData = $Files | Where-Object { test-NoMetaData $_ }
```

You could also place the code directly in the `Where-Object` block and refer to `$_` directly.

**Optional reading**: If you want to make the function more sophisticated, read on.

---

Consider implementing **a `Filter` function that you can use *directly* in the pipeline**:

```
Filter select-WithMetaData {
  param([switch] $NotPresent) #  To invert the logic
  if ($Args) { Throw "Unrecognized arguments: $Args" }
  if (-not $MyInvocation.ExpectingInput) { return } # no pipeline input; nothing to do.
  $haveAllMetaData = $True
  foreach ($propName in 'Vendor', 'Company', 'Product', 'Description') {
    if ($_.$propName -le 1) { $haveAllMetaData = $False; break }
  }
  # Pass the input object through only if it has/doesn't have the requisite metadata.
  if ($haveAllMetaData -ne $NotPresent) { $_ }
}

$filesWithoutMetaData = $Files | select-WithMetaData -NotPresent
$filesWithMetaData =    $Files | select-WithMetaData
```

`Filter`s are simplified functions that make it easier to define functionality that *only* accepts pipeline input: the body of the `Filter` function is invoked for *each input object* and `$_` refers to that input object.

`Filter` functions are convenient, but have down-sides:

- You cannot pass input as direct arguments as an alternative to pipeline input (unless you explicitly define a pipeline-binding parameter, which nullifies the advantages of the simplified syntax that `Filter` offers).
- You cannot run initialization / cleanup code before / after pipeline input is received.

Use `Function` syntax to avoid these limitations - see below.

---

To write **a function that *alternatively* accepts direct argument input** and **supports common parameters** (which makes it an ***advanced* function** (cmdlet-like)), you must use the `Function` construct and explicitly declare a parameter as accepting pipeline input.

Additionally, your function must have a `process { ... }` block, which is invoked for each input item;  optionally, it can have a `begin {...}` and an `end { ... }` block for pre-pipeline-input initialization / post-pipeline-input cleanup.
**Caveat**: If you do *not* use a `process` block, your function is only invoked *once*, at which point the pipeline-binding parameter variable only contains the *last* input object.

PSv3+ syntax:

```
Function Select-WithMetaData {
  [CmdletBinding()] # Make this an advanced function with common-parameter support.
  param(
    # Declare -File as accepting a single file directly or multiple files via the pipeline.
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline, Mandatory)] [object] $File,
    [switch] $NotPresent
  )

  # Invoked once with a directly passed -File argument bound to $File,
  # and for each input object, also bound to $File, if used in the pipeline.
  process { 
    $haveAllMetaData = $True
    foreach ($propName in 'Vendor', 'Company', 'Product', 'Description') {
      if ($File.$propName -le 1) { $haveAllMetaData = $False; break }
    }
    if ($haveAllMetaData -ne $NotPresent) { $File }
  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have modified the function slightly and this looks to be working well. Thanks to @mklement0

```
Function Test-AcMetadata {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess = $False)]
    [OutputType([Bool])]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = $True, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $False)]
        [object]$obj
    )
    ForEach ($Property in 'Vendor', 'Company', 'Product', 'Description') {
        If ($obj.$Property -ge 2) { Return $True }
    }
    Return $False
}
```

Which enables filtering for metadata or no metadata:

```
$NoMetadata = $Files | Where-Object { (Test-AcMetadata $_) -eq $False }
$Metadata = $Files | Where-Object { Test-AcMetadata $_ }
```

Comment: I am glad you found a solution, but your modifications to my approach are largely incidental to solving your core problem _as asked_, so in effect you've created a duplicate with distracting elements. Also note that in your example invocations you're (a) not taking advantage of the pipeline support and that (b) it wouldn't work, because as written your function would only
ever process the _last_ object in the pipeline. It's fine to demonstrate additional features and good practices in an answer, but I suggest doing that separately, as I've tried to do in my since-updated answer.

Comment: @mklement0 your answer is great! It's just ashamed the OP did not take it to heart. You can only lead them to water its up to them to drink.